# Smoothness of an even function of a square root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

My conventions: a real-valued function on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is **smooth** if its partial derivatives of all orders exist and are continuous. A real-valued function on an arbitrary subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is **smooth** if it can be extended to a smooth function on an open subset containing $A$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Furthermore, assume that $f$ is even with respect to its second input (i.e. $f(x,y)=f(x,-y)$. Is then the map \begin{align*}\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty)&\to\mathbb{R}\\(x,y)&\mapsto f(x,\sqrt{y})\end{align*} smooth?

I've seen some similar questions here, but I haven't seen one treating the case with two variables.

Comment: Your question is essentially one-dimensional. The $x$-variable apparently is superfluous. Can you answer the one-dimensional question, i.e. $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is even and $C^{\infty}$, is then $f(\sqrt{y})$ also smooth?

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes. We expand $f(y)$ in a Taylor polynomial around $y=0$, and in this polynomial all of the odd terms vanish, and thus $f(\sqrt{y})$ is approximated by a polynomial in $y$. This can be done to arbitrarily high order, which implies that $f(\sqrt{y})$ is differentiable (with respect to $y$) of all orders. But this uses the fact that the existence of all derivatives implies smoothness, which holds only in one dimension. In two dimensions, we also need to prove that the partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: So you are in fact asking whether the partial derivatives of $f(x,\sqrt{y})$ of all orders to exist in $\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is false. As indicated in comment, this is essentially a one dimensional problem. Take $\varphi\in C^\infty$ be compactly supported, even and such that $\varphi = 1$ in a ball near $0$, and define
$$
f(y) = \varphi(y)\,|y|^2
$$
Then
$$
f(\sqrt y) = \varphi(y)\,|y|
$$
is not differentiable at $x=0$ (I think your mistake was coming from the fact that you simplified $\sqrt{y^2} = y$ instead of $|y[$).